# How to get absolute values of all elements in a list?

Tags: c#, lambda

I want to do something like below:

```
total.ForEach(x => x = Math.Abs(x));
```

However x is not a reference value. How would I go about doing it?

Edit:

Is it possible to do this in place and not creating another list and not using a for loop?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

You can use Linq.

```
total.Select(x => Math.Abs(x)).ToList();
```

That will give you a new list of the absolute values in `total`.
If you want to modify in place

```
for(int i = 0; i < total.Count; i++)
{
     total[i] = Math.Abs(total[i]);
}
```

Answer (score 4):

If I understand correcly you want list of abs values. Try something like

```
 List<long> a = new List<long>() { 10, -30, 40 }; //original list
 List<long> b = a.ConvertAll<long>(x => Math.Abs(x)); //abs list
```

Answer (score 0):

This will be slightly more efficient as uses less method calls.

```
total.Select(x => x * -1).ToList();
```

Comment: How `* -1` turn a value to its absolute value ? It only work for negative value. For positive ones it will turns them to negative.